# Count of records for the last and current month unix timestamp

Tags: mysql, select, count, unix-timestamp

I need to make statistics page for billing with auto query. For example now is july and query must show count of record for the june and current count of records on current day(only july). Sort of:

"records for the last month - 85, for the current day - 32"

I have table `customer` and row `create_time` but it is in unix timestamp. Tried

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `customer` WHERE `create_time` >=
>   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))

but its absolutely not what i want.

I would appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_previous_month
           FROM customer
          WHERE create_time >= concat(date_format(LAST_DAY(now() - interval 1 month),'%Y-%m-'),'01')
            AND create_time < LAST_DAY(now() - interval 1 month )
       ) AS s1,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_previous_month
           FROM customer
          WHERE create_time >= concat(extract(year from now()),'-',extract(month from now()),'-01')
            AND create_time <= now()
       ) AS s2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding condition to the WHERE:

```
create_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 month))
```

in PHP you can calculate the one month back date

```
$newDate = strtotime('-1 month');
```

and use this in query